# Adding objects for each item added from scraping data from a website

Tags: python, object, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to retrieve data from a website with and add for each row of data and object, I am new to python and I clearly miss something because I can get only 1 object, what Im trying to get is all the objects I get sorted by key value pairs:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

url = 'http://freemusicarchive.org/search/?quicksearch=drake/'
search = ''
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tracks_info = [{}]

spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ptxt-artist'})
for span in spans:
    arts = span.find_all('a')
    for art in arts:
        print(art.text)

spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ptxt-track'})
for span in spans:
    tracks = span.find_all('a')
    for track in tracks:
        print(track.text)

for download_links in soup.find_all('a', {'title': 'Download'}):
    print(download_links.get('href'))

for info in tracks_info:
    info.update({'artist': art.text})
    info.update({'track': track.text})
    info.update({'link': download_links.get('href')})



    print(info)
```

I failed to add an object for each element I get from the website, Im clearly doing something wrong\or not doing and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a slightly different struture and syntax such as below.

I use a contains CSS class selector to retrieve the rows of info as the id is different for each track

[image]

The CSS selector combination of `div[class*="play-item gcol gid-electronic tid-"]`
looks for div elements with class attribute having value containing `play-item gcol gid-electronic tid-`.

Within that the various *columns* of interest are then selected by their class name and a descendant css selector is used for the `a` tag element for the final download link.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://freemusicarchive.org/search/?quicksearch=drake/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tracks_Info = []    
headRow = ['Artist','TrackName','DownloadLink']

for item in soup.select('div[class*="play-item gcol gid-electronic tid-"]'):
    tracks_Info.append([item.select_one(".ptxt-artist").text.strip(), item.select_one(".ptxt-track").text, item.select_one(".playicn a").get('href')])

df = pd.DataFrame(tracks_Info,columns=headRow)

print(df)
```

Comment: Great, I will give this a try, seems like the logic I should have done except I didnt know the pandas tool, thanks a lot!!!